# Writing a GET request that takes multiple query paramters

Tags: python, rest, http, curl, restful-url

I am writing a GET request that takes three query paramters in the end of the URL

Now a URL in my list of urls is

```
(r'/v1/random/data?{}' .format(urllib.urlencode(args)) , 'GET', getResource),
```

The method getResource redirects to a class where the parameters are to be extracted from the URL
I have printed the local variables using locals() in that particular method and they are as such

```
{'res': {}, 'args': 'data', 'uri': '/v1/random/data', 'entities': ['', 'v1', 'random', 'data'] }
```

The curl request for the above output is

```
curl -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET http://<ip>:<port>/v1/<random>/data?param1=1&param2=2
```

I want to be able to extract the parameters param1 and param2 from my curl request. How should I implement this in Python ?

IF you dont understand the error above, I want to create an API in python such that

```
curl "http://localhost:5000/pulse/?lat=41.225&lon=-73.1"
```

that is able to accept two values in a GET request

Comment: Just to clarify: You want to extract the parameters `param1` and `param2` from you curl request? Where do you get these requests from since you have to pass them to Python?

Comment: @Albert: Yes I want to extract param1 and param2. I have a server running to which we can make these curl requests and I have to return the correct response according to the request.

Comment: You need to be a bit more specific. What are you running on the server? Are you using a framework?

Comment: @DanielRoseman: Yes, Gunicorn is the framework and I inherit the class gunicorn.app.base.BaseApplication

Answer (score 3):

Can you use [Requests](http://www.python-requests.org/)?  If so, it's as simple as (example from home page):

```
payload = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}
r = requests.get("http://httpbin.org/get", params=payload)
```

Update:

To produce the exact query string shown in your last CURL example with Requests, you could do:

```
p = {'lat':41.225, 'lon'=-73.1 }
r = requests.get( 'http://localhost:5000/pulse/', params=p )
```

Comment: The above is a GET API and the more I read the more i get to know that get requests shouldnt have query params in the payload
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body

Comment: This will put the parameters in the URL string, not a separate HTTP request body/payload as seen in POSTs.   `payload` is just the name of the python variable (perhaps poorly chosen).

Comment: Indeed poorly choosen then :)
+1 for your answer. 
Can it be done with gunicorn on which my code base is currently built ?